# How to use MySqlOperator with xcom in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I read this [How to use airflow xcoms with MySqlOperator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46670328/how-to-use-airflow-xcoms-with-mysqloperator) and while it has a similiar title it doesn't really address my issue.

I have the following code:

```
def branch_func_is_new_records(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    xcom = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='query_get_max_order_id')
    string_to_print = 'Value in xcom is: {}'.format(xcom)
    logging.info(string_to_print)
    if int(xcom) > int(LAST_IMPORTED_ORDER_ID)
        return 'import_orders'
    else:
        return 'skip_operation'

query_get_max_order_id  = 'SELECT COALESCE(max(orders_id),0) FROM warehouse.orders where orders_id>1 limit 10'
get_max_order_id = MySqlOperator(
        task_id='query_get_max_order_id',
        sql= query_get_max_order_id,
        mysql_conn_id=MyCon,
        xcom_push=True,
        dag=dag)

branch_op_is_new_records = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='branch_operation_is_new_records',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=branch_func_is_new_records,
    dag=dag)

get_max_order_id >> branch_op_is_new_records >> import_orders
branch_op_is_new_records >> skip_operation
```

The `MySqlOperator` returns a number according to the number the `BranchPythonOperator` choose the next task. It's guaranteed that the `MySqlOperator` has returned value greater than `0`.

My problem is that nothing is pushed to `XCOM` by the `MySqlOperator`
On the UI when I go to `XCOM` I see nothing. The `BranchPythonOperator` oviously reads nothing so my code fails.

Why the `XCOM` doesn't work here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MySQL operator currently (airflow 1.10.0 at time of writing) doesn't support returning anything in XCom, so the fix for you for now is to write a small operator yourself. You can do this directly in your DAG file (untested, so there may be silly errors):

```
from airflow.operators.mysql_operator import MySqlOperator as BaseMySqlOperator
from airflow.hooks.mysql_hook import MySqlHook

class ReturningMySqlOperator(BaseMySqlOperator):
    def execute(self, context):
        self.log.info('Executing: %s', self.sql)
        hook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id=self.mysql_conn_id,
                         schema=self.database)
        return hook.get_first(
            self.sql,
            parameters=self.parameters)


def branch_func_is_new_records(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    xcom = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='query_get_max_order_id')
    string_to_print = 'Value in xcom is: {}'.format(xcom)
    logging.info(string_to_print)
    if str(xcom) == 'NewRecords':
        return 'import_orders'
    else:
        return 'skip_operation'

query_get_max_order_id  = 'SELECT COALESCE(max(orders_id),0) FROM warehouse.orders where orders_id>1 limit 10'
get_max_order_id = ReturningMySqlOperator(
        task_id='query_get_max_order_id',
        sql= query_get_max_order_id,
        mysql_conn_id=MyCon,
        # xcom_push=True,
        dag=dag)

branch_op_is_new_records = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='branch_operation_is_new_records',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=branch_func_is_new_records,
    dag=dag)

get_max_order_id >> branch_op_is_new_records >> import_orders
branch_op_is_new_records >> skip_operation
```

Comment: Is this ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='query_get_max_order_id') correct? do I need xcom_pull if I not use xcom?

Comment: `query_get_max_order_id` is right for this example.

Comment: `xcom_push` is not a magic flag understood by Airflow, it's something each operator needs to implement/understand - and the custom operator always returns a value to xcom, so you don't need it here.